# Proof that minimum of sum of absolute differences is greater or equal of max value minus min value

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, discrete-optimization, formal-proofs

Let's have an vector of natural numbers $[v_1, ..., v_N]$ my goal is to show that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}|v_i - v_{i+1}| \ge v_{max} - v_{min}$$ 
where $v_{max} = \max_{i\in1...N}(v_i)$ and $v_{min} = \min_{i\in1...N}(v_i)$. I can intuitively convenience myself that this is true. I rationalize that those difference are like difference of heights of subsequence peaks and to climb from the lowest to the highest my altitude has to change at least by $v_{max} - v_{min}$ but I am not able to create formal proof of this statement.

Comment: HINT: Apply triangular inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $m$ and $n$ be indices in $\{1,2\ldots, N\}$ such that $v_m = v_{\max}$ and $v_n = v_\min$. If $m = n$, then $v_m - v_n = 0$ and the result is clear. Assume, without loss of generality, that $m > n$. By the triangle inequality,

\begin{align}v_m - v_n &= |(v_m - v_{m-1}) + (v_{m-1} - v_{m-2}) + \cdots + (v_{n-1} - v_n)|\\
& \le \sum_{i = n}^{m-1} |v_i - v_{i+1}|\\
& \le \sum_{i = 1}^{N-1}|v_i - v_{i+1}|.
\end{align}

Note: You could technically avoid using the triangle inequality by removing the absolute value bars in the first equation and using the inequality $x \le |x|$ for all real numbers $x$.

Comment: $v_m$ and $v_n$ does not have to be adjacent ($|m-n|=1$) so you can not just apply triangle inequality.

Comment: Adjacency is not needed.

Comment: There is no any step in your proof that would really prove first inequality. Triangle inequality is really property of metric and it concerns exactly three points which is not the case in first inequality.

Comment: Note that the absolute value is a metric on $\Bbb R$ (in particular, on $\Bbb N$). Also, the first inequality is follows from repeated applications of the triangle inequality.  Without loss of generality, assume $m > n$. Then $$|v_m - v_n| = |(v_m - v_{m-1}) + (v_{m-1} - v_{m-2}) + \cdots + (v_{n-1} - v_n)| \le |v_m - v_{m-1}| + |v_{m-1} - v_{m-2}| + \cdots + |v_{n-1} - v_n|,$$ and the sum on the right-hand side is $\sum_{i = n}^{m-1}|v_i - v_{i+1}|$.

Comment: Please add this explanation of first inequality to answer body and I will accept it.